# Wordpress Mobile menu does not close after pressing meniu item

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu, anchor

Good day,

So i made a WordPress site for a construction company and i cant make the mobile menu work... Its a one page site, so the menu links are Anchors like #about us, #services, etc... And the desktop version is working perfectly, but when we go to mobile, open the menu and press on one of the items, the menu does not close and if you close it manually the site scrolls up instantly.

The site: https://www.eko-bau.eu/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a mobile menu plugin - WP Mobile Menu